# Can't purge old kernels (dependency problems), but /boot is out of space

Tags: ubuntu, apt, linux-kernel, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, and I'm trying to install a new package using apt-get. Unfortunately, whenever I try I get messages like:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic (= 3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Doing some googling, I found that [this can be caused by lack of space on the boot partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719481/cant-install-anything-anymore-unmet-dependencies-for-linux-image) (and sure enough, `df` shows `/boot` at 100%). However, any time I try running the `apt-get` commands in the accepted answer there, I get the same errors as above.

Looking for another solution that didn't use `apt-get`, I came across [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels), which recommends using things like `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.2.0-15-generic` on old, unused kernels.

`dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)` (from the afore-mentioned post) shows that I have several old kernels in the `pi` state (desired purged, state is installed according to [this](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/))

`uname -r` tells me the kernel I'm running is 3.16.0-62-generic, so I thought I should be safe to remove these old kernels. However, trying to do so with things like `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic` results in:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic
```

Garrg! I'm at my wit's end, and out of my depth (don't really know much about dpkg or apt-get), so I need some help.

**Questions:**

1. Why can't I uninstall the old kernels with `dpkg`?
2. If that question can't be directly solved, I guess ultimately I want to know: *What do I need to do to get into a state where I can install new packages again?*

---

**Other things I have tried**:

- `sudo apt-get autoremove` : results in the original error about unmet dependencies
- `sudo apt-get -f autoremove` : results in:

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic (3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic_3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic_3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the output of `dpkg` told the kernel depends on:

```
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic
```

The instructions tell you should purge that first (or by the same command). I have updated the instructions in the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki, which is currently located at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels