# Update ubuntu 16.04 base and crash... Uh oh!

Tags: ubuntu, boot, upgrade, system-failure

Installed the latest base updates. Running 16.04. Says updates failed and calls for a reboot... Bad things happen.

Is there a way to get to my interface without reinstalling the system?

[image: my screen]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! When the GRUB loads with options, select "Advanced Options".

There will be a list of the currently installed and previously installed Linux kernels. My current was a 4.4 version, so I selected one further back, and... I'm able to write this from my desktop :0)

One problem that may have messed with the update was that my /boot folder was all full up.  Not entirely certain how to fix that just yet, but this will work for now.

Comment: remove older kernels that you no longer want to boot

Comment: What's a good command line way to do that?

Comment: [one example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281752/117549), [another example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333275/delete-new-kernels-boot-full)